# Best way to set default header for all request in flutter http request

Tags: http, dart, header, flutter

Sorry if this question so basic, but I am new to flutter and recently couldn't find a good way to set a default headers in the HTTP request I can extend the class or wrap a function to it but shouldn't it there be an easy way that is build-in but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be easily made with the Dio package.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio

**Update**

Based on the new Dio API:

```
var dio = Dio();
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
  var customHeaders = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    // other headers
  };
  options.headers.addAll(customHeaders);
  return options;
}));

Response response = await dio.get("url");
print(response.data.toString());
```

Refer the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#interceptors) for more details.

Comment: intercepting it midway I really like this solution it the most simplest way to go

Comment: Will this dio object be shared amongst all my widgets? If not, this setting will only affect this dio object.

Comment: This package has a breaking error, where if a server throws a >= 400, an uncatchable exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 21):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyClient extends http.BaseClient{
  http.Client _httpClient = new http.Client();

  MyClient(Map defaultHeaders);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers.addAll(defaultHeaders);
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate another Http client. Returning ```request.send()``` also works :)

Comment: @GuilhermeV. If you do that, you will be creating a new http client on every request, instead of re-using the existing client, which is probably a persistent connection.

Answer (score 12):

#### Register custom HttpClientFactory

Dart allows to register a factory for creating an `HttpClient`

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return new MyHttpClient(super.createHttpClient(context));
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

#### Implement custom HttpClient

Implementing such a custom `HttpClient` seems overly complicated, but perhaps there is a better way.

The class implements `HttpClient` from `dart:io` and all its abstract classes.

The methods `get(...)` and `getUrl(...)` are customized to add a custom header using `_updateHeaders(...)`. You would need to extend that to all other methods like `head`, `headUrl`, `open`, `post`, ...

```
import 'dart:io';

class MyHttpClient implements HttpClient {
  HttpClient _realClient;

  MyHttpClient(this._realClient);

  @override
  bool get autoUncompress => _realClient.autoUncompress;

  @override
  set autoUncompress(bool value) => _realClient.autoUncompress = value;

  @override
  Duration get connectionTimeout => _realClient.connectionTimeout;

  @override
  set connectionTimeout(Duration value) =>
      _realClient.connectionTimeout = value;

  @override
  Duration get idleTimeout => _realClient.idleTimeout;

  @override
  set idleTimeout(Duration value) => _realClient.idleTimeout = value;

  @override
  int get maxConnectionsPerHost => _realClient.maxConnectionsPerHost;

  @override
  set maxConnectionsPerHost(int value) =>
      _realClient.maxConnectionsPerHost = value;

  @override
  String get userAgent => _realClient.userAgent;

  @override
  set userAgent(String value) => _realClient.userAgent = value;

  @override
  void addCredentials(
          Uri url, String realm, HttpClientCredentials credentials) =>
      _realClient.addCredentials(url, realm, credentials);

  @override
  void addProxyCredentials(String host, int port, String realm,
          HttpClientCredentials credentials) =>
      _realClient.addProxyCredentials(host, port, realm, credentials);

  @override
  void set authenticate(
          Future<bool> Function(Uri url, String scheme, String realm) f) =>
      _realClient.authenticate = f;

  @override
  void set authenticateProxy(
          Future<bool> Function(
                  String host, int port, String scheme, String realm)
              f) =>
      _realClient.authenticateProxy = f;

  @override
  void set badCertificateCallback(
          bool Function(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)
              callback) =>
      _realClient.badCertificateCallback = callback;

  @override
  void close({bool force = false}) => _realClient.close(force: force);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> delete(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.delete(host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> deleteUrl(Uri url) => _realClient.deleteUrl(url);

  @override
  void set findProxy(String Function(Uri url) f) => _realClient.findProxy = f;

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> get(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _updateHeaders(_realClient.get(host, port, path));

  Future<HttpClientRequest> _updateHeaders(
      Future<HttpClientRequest> httpClientRequest) async {
    return (await httpClientRequest)..headers.add('foo', 'bar');
  }

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> getUrl(Uri url) =>
      _updateHeaders(_realClient.getUrl(url.replace(path: url.path)));

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> head(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.head(host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> headUrl(Uri url) => _realClient.headUrl(url);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> open(
          String method, String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.open(method, host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> openUrl(String method, Uri url) =>
      _realClient.openUrl(method, url);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> patch(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.patch(host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> patchUrl(Uri url) => _realClient.patchUrl(url);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> post(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.post(host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> postUrl(Uri url) => _realClient.postUrl(url);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> put(String host, int port, String path) =>
      _realClient.put(host, port, path);

  @override
  Future<HttpClientRequest> putUrl(Uri url) => _realClient.putUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: I found it useful but still I think is a little bit over complicated

Comment: I think so as well.

Answer (score 10):

this simple and easy way worked for me

```
var _dio = Dio();
_dio.options.headers= {"Authorization" : token};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on @Radek Manasek idea of a custom `Client`, I'm overriding all the methods so you don't have to write them again.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class MyClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _defaultHeaders;
  http.Client _httpClient = http.Client();

  MyClient(this._defaultHeaders);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> get(url, {Map<String, String> headers}) {
    return _httpClient.get(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers));
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> post(url, {Map<String, String> headers, dynamic body, Encoding encoding}) {
    return _httpClient.post(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers), body: body, encoding: encoding);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> patch(url, {Map<String, String> headers, dynamic body, Encoding encoding}) {
    return _httpClient.patch(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers), body: body, encoding: encoding);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> put(url, {Map<String, String> headers, dynamic body, Encoding encoding}) {
    return _httpClient.put(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers), body: body, encoding: encoding);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> head(url, {Map<String, String> headers}) {
    return _httpClient.head(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers));
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> delete(url, {Map<String, String> headers}) {
    return _httpClient.delete(url, headers: _mergedHeaders(headers));
  }

  Map<String, String> _mergedHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) =>
      {...?_defaultHeaders, ...?headers};
}
```

Comment: How can this work with global HTTP overrides? HttpOverrides.createHttpClient needs to return an HttpClient instead of a BaseClient.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a singleton class and initilizing dio in it and using it in all my controllers which need to do http requests.

There is 2 ways to add headers in dio client first is

```
_dio.interceptors.addAll([
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest: (options, handler) {
          options.headers.addAll({'authorization': 'Bearer $_authToken'});
          handler.next(options);
        },
      ),
      CustomInterceptors(), // your other interceptors
    ]);
```

and 2nd one is like this

```
  void setAuthToken(String token) {
    _authToken = token;
    _dio.options.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
  }
```

First method will add headers before making each request so, we can add conditional based on our business logic. so first method is much better then 2nd method.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @Radek and @vovahost just made their implementation applicable to library updates and added function to check status code and throw error in certain responses.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class BaseNetworkClient extends http.BaseClient {
  Map<String, String> _defaultHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  final http.Client _httpClient = http.Client();

  addTokenToHeader(String token) {
    _mergedHeaders({"auth_token": token});
  }

  Map<String, String> _mergedHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) =>
      {...?_defaultHeaders, ...?headers};

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _httpClient.send(request).then((response) async {
      _checkError( await http.Response.fromStream(response));


      return response;
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> get(url, {Map<String, String>? headers}) {
    return _httpClient
        .get(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> post(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers, dynamic body, Encoding? encoding}) {
    return _httpClient
        .post(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders,
            body: body,
            encoding: encoding)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> patch(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers, dynamic body, Encoding? encoding}) {
    return _httpClient
        .patch(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders,
            body: body,
            encoding: encoding)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> put(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers, dynamic body, Encoding? encoding}) {
    return _httpClient
        .put(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders,
            body: body,
            encoding: encoding)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> head(url, {Map<String, String>? headers}) {
    return _httpClient
        .head(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> delete(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers, Object? body, Encoding? encoding}) {
    return _httpClient
        .delete(url,
            headers:
                headers != null ? _mergedHeaders(headers) : _defaultHeaders)
        .then(_checkError);
  }

  Response _checkError(Response response) {
    final int? statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode == null) {
    throw  //Todoo: add custom exception don't expect response.body
      
    
    } else if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
      throw  //Todoo: add custom exception 
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```