# How to give default headers in all http requests in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I found an answer with dio package here [Best way to set default header for all request in flutter http request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54321077/15105824) but i done a lot of work without using dio.

Comment: why not making a custom function that uses the headers and call it when ever you want?

Comment: Are you using the futter http package?

Comment: there is lot of functions .so i need to be call it in every function,it will be better if there is another way

Comment: yes i am using http package

Comment: In the [Http package's ReadMe](https://pub.dev/packages/http) see the last paragraph under the `Using` section, they outline a method for extending the base client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a way with http package by extending the base client

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
class MyClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final http.Client _httpClient = http.Client();

  MyClient();

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    var defaultHeaders = <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     
    };
    request.headers.addAll(defaultHeaders);
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }
}
```

use class name instead of http in http requests